# what difference does 'apply' makes when sending array as arguments to a variable arity function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here i have a function which can take any number of arguments.Sending an array as argument to this function without apply creates an Array which **contains an  Array** having 3 elements.

```
function a(){
   console.log(arguments);
}
a([1,2,3]);
```

[image]

When it is called with apply() method it gives an output with only a single array having its elements

```
function a(){
   console.log(arguments);
}
a.apply(null,[1,2,3]);
```

[image]

We can see a significant change in output.I only know we have My question is what difference does apply make when we send array as arguments??I mean **why we need to use 'apply' when we have to send an array to a variadic?**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Reading the docs would have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` has nothing to do with sending arrays to a function.

It's for invoking a function and specifying a specific `this` context for the function. You can pass arguments to the function in question as an array with the second argument to `apply`, or as N subsequent arguments to `call`.

The entire point of `apply` and `call` is the *first* argument, which you've set to `null`, not the arguments after that.

Comment: actually what i have asked is why there is a difference in the output pattern in the console?

Comment: @user3138436 Why **wouldn't** there be a difference? You're using `apply` in one example, and you're **not** using it in the other example. Of course there is a difference. Did you read the documentation about what `apply` does?